# WebGL inspect images in samplers (similar to Renderdoc)?

Tags: javascript, debugging, glsl, webgl, renderdoc

Is there a debugging tool in any browser, as an extension or otherwise, or any tool, that I could use to visualize the image loaded into a 2d sampler in GLSL?

Essentially something that has the same functionality as renderdoc but for WebGL.

Comment: WebGL Inspector https://benvanik.github.io/WebGL-Inspector/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Spector.js](https://spector.babylonjs.com/) can show textures bound to texture units and a ton of other useful for debugging information.